# How to activate horizontal ScrollView if indexes from List is more than 20 and stretch the chart - using xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I have a chart with dynamically data.

So I want when the indexes from the list is more than 20 to be activated horizontal `Scrollview` and my chart to be stretched horizontally ?

My .xaml file look like this:

```
 <ScrollView>
       <StackLayout>
             <microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartView" 
                                    HeightRequest="100"
                                    BackgroundColor="#f7f77c"/>
       </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

My .cs code with filled data look like this:

```
List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                entries.Add(
                    new Entry((float)result[i].Stoej)
                    {
                        Color = SKColor.Parse("#FF1943"),
                        Label = result[i].D.ToString(),
                        ValueLabel = result[i].Stoej.ToString()
                    });
            }

chartView.Chart = new LineChart()
                {
                    Entries = entries,
                    LineMode = LineMode.Spline,
                    LineSize = 8,
                    PointMode = PointMode.Circle,
                    PointSize = 18,
                    LabelTextSize = 40,
                    BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent
                };
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I try like this but the chart is not stretching horizontally:

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happened because the width of `ChartView` is fixed(equal to screen width), we need to set the width manually in code behind .

```
int itemWidth = 20;   //define by you
chartView.WidthRequest = entries.Count * itemWidth;
```

And don't forget to set `scroll.Orientation="Horizontal"` first .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your list is > 20 to enable:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scroll" isEnabled="false">
       <StackLayout>
             <microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartView" 
                                    HeightRequest="100"
                                    BackgroundColor="#f7f77c"/>
       </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>

List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                entries.Add(
                    new Entry((float)result[i].Stoej)
                    {
                        Color = SKColor.Parse("#FF1943"),
                        Label = result[i].D.ToString(),
                        ValueLabel = result[i].Stoej.ToString()
                    });
            }
            if(entries.Count > 20)
            {
              scroll.IsEnabled = true;
              scroll.HorizontalBarVisibility = Always;
            }
```

Or automatically let scroll enabled, so if the list begins to jump of the user device screen, scrolls will be adjusting.

Comment: Ok, but the chart not stretch horizontally. Can you check my updated question, please. I upload a screenshot. I want when the indexes is more than 20 chart to be stretched with scrollview, for now I have too much data in too little space and I cannot see anything.

Comment: "the chart not stretch horizontally", please, put `scroll.Orientation="Horizontal"` and see if it works. If it's still not stretching, use Grid. Check this link to update your code with Grid (if you have any doubts of how you can implement it, please, update your code with what you will achieve and we can help you):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid

Comment: I will check and will response here :) thanks :)